# Using where clause with Group Joins in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Iam new to LINQ, but i don't know what's wrong with this piece of code. All i want is to store the result from the query in an array list and it gives me the Exception: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

```
             var JoinLCandSymp =
             (from symp in SymptomsTable.AsEnumerable()
              join leftC in LeftChestTable.AsEnumerable() on symp.Field<int>("Symptom_Number") equals leftC.Field<int>("Symptom_Number") into Sgroup

              from SF in Sgroup
              where SF.Field<int>("Rank") == 1 && SF.Field<string>("Category") == "Pain"

              select symp.Field<string>("Symptom_Name")

               );
         foreach (string val in JoinLCandSymp)
         {

             GlobalVariables.sympLCWR1Pain.Add(val);

         }
```

any help would really be helpful. :)

Ok, well, here's another of the same procedure...what might wrong with this? Gives the same exception.

```
         var JoinLCandSymp =
         (from symp in SymptomsTable.AsEnumerable()
          join leftC in LeftChestTable.AsEnumerable() on symp.Field<int>("Symptom_Number") equals leftC.Field<int>("Symptom_Number")
          where leftC.Field<int>("Rank") == 1 && leftC.Field<string>("Category") == "Pain"
         // group leftC by symp into SympGroup
          select symp.Field<string>("Symptom_Name")

           );
     foreach (string val in JoinLCandSymp)
     {

         GlobalVariables.sympLCWR1Pain.Add(val);

     }
```

Comment: I would need to see the SQL that is populating the dataset. But without that, something is null: Rank, Category, or Sympton_Number. When you try to access the column, it is failing.

Comment: The SymptomsTable is populated and so is LeftChestTable..Rank and Category are columns of the of the LeftChestTable..Symptom_Number is both a column of the SymptomsTable and LeftChestTable..and i can access their columns without any problem

Comment: I got it, lad...the latter code works now..i was using a non-static array list when in coordination with a class i had to use a static one..my bad :p..thanks anyways

Comment: Why are you always calling `AsEnumerable()`? That could make your code horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better is using a View or a USP ( User Store Procedore), when do you use a USP in .Net do you return a same tape of data.

Comment: i have to use linq along with a bit of ADO.net